# Formatting timestamp in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, format

We have a column of type varchar2(200 char) which holds a timestamp in the format **2019-03-28:17:01:44.407000000**
Now we would like to update the values in the column so that the format looks like **3/28/2019 5:01:43.475 PM**
We are using Oracle 12c.

I am new to oracle, Any lead would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a pretty terrible data model.  A timestamp should really, really be stored in a `timestamp` column rather than in a `varchar2`.  Both because then the data type identifies what is actually in the column and because it is more efficient and because it lets you use all Oracle's timestamp functions on the data sensibly.

Assuming that you are stuck with an incorrect data model

```
update your_table
   set your_column = to_char( to_timestamp( your_column, 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS.FF9' ),
                              'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF3 PM' )
```

would update all the data to the new format in the unlikely event that every single value in the table is in the correct format already.  In most real-world systems, you'd need to do a fair amount of clean-up first because inevitably someone has stored in incorrect string or two in your column.

If you do happen to be able to update all the data successfully, be aware that any queries that do `order by your_column` will almost certainly stop doing what you want.  Since the column is a `varchar2` rather than a `timestamp`, sorting is done alphabetically rather than by the point in time that the string represents.  If you change the format to something where temporal order doesn't match alphabetical order, you are likely to have unhappy users.

Comment: Thanks a lot Justin. This worked 
select column_name, to_char(to_timestamp(column_name, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.**FF3** PM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD:HH24:MI:SS.**FF**') from table_name

We use SAP Hybris and the DB is MSSQL, now we are doing a DB migration to Oracle. Some tables are not auto generated by Hybris, so we manually migrated them. Hybris took care of the format for the tables that are generated. Now we are trying to format the column according to the Hybris.